# Networking in Azure. Openswan inside Azure up but won't route packet

Tags: networking, vpn, firewall, azure

I have set up a VPN using ubuntu 14.04 and openswan on azure 192.168.0.5. I have another box ubuntuapp behind the openswan in the same subnet 192.168.0.6(only encryption domain on azure). The right side has encryption domain of 172.31.20.10 and 172.31.20.12.

While I can connect from 192.168.0.6 azure side to the all 172.31.. encryption domain on 8080. I can't connect the 172.31. network to 192.168.0.6:80 even though port TCP 80 has been opened for both 172.31.20.10 and 172.31.20.12.

```
192.168.0.6 --> 172.31.20.10:8080 [yes]
192.168.0.6 --> 172.31.20.12:8080 [yes]
```

Connection to Azure

```
172.31.20.10 --> 192.168.0.6:80 [no]
172.31.20.12 --> 192.168.0.6:80 [no]
```

I know by default boxes on the save vnet can reach each other thanks to the default rules. Should there be a specific rule between ubuntuapp and openswan and vice versa? If yes kindly enlighten me.

**EDIT**

With some little tcpdump search I found out that the openswan box doesn't seem to know where to send the packet to

```
14:52:27.623074 IP 192.168.0.5.65000 > 192.168.0.6.65001: Flags [R], seq 0, win 0, length 0
14:52:27.623142 IP 192.168.0.5.65000 > 192.168.0.6.65001: Flags [R], seq 0, win 0, length 0
14:52:32.629621 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.0.6 tell 192.168.0.5, length 28
14:53:36.683792 IP 192.168.0.5.65000 > 192.168.0.6.65001: Flags [R], seq 0, win 0, length 0
14:53:36.683865 IP 192.168.0.5.65000 > 192.168.0.6.65001: Flags [R], seq 0, win 0, length 0
```

But ping or telnet from 192.168.0.5 to 192.168.0.6 works fine.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that was missing was nat traversal on vyos vpn configuration

```
set vpn ipsec nat-traversal enable
```

This was added to the configuration and it's all fine now.

Answer (score 0):

From what I could understand you have everything right except IP forwarding and UDR. The following article will help you with the configuration and general understanding.

**Create User-Defined Routes (UDR) using PowerShell**:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-create-udr-arm-ps

Once you enable IP forwarding, you have to explicitly tell Azure what's the next hop, otherwise, it will try to use Azure standard network gateway to reach the desired location.

I believe your virtual VPN appliance have to sit in another subnet in order for this to work as well.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I got to know what was missing. NAT traversal wasn't enabled on VyOS vpn config....foolishly